# Web page background not updating after ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I've searched and can't find an answer to this. Sorry if I have missed it.

I have a page that has a drop down box with a list of templates. After the user selects a template, the various options available for editing appear below in a div.

When the edit options appear, it forces the page to scroll and the area where it now scrolls does not have the background color of the page. (I would post a screenshot, but the system won't let me.) Instead, it's just a flat grey color in the newly scrolling area.

This is my .js for updating the div:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#ecbs_styles").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $j("#ecbs_styles option:selected").each(function() {
            str = $j("#ecbs_styles").val();
            try {
                $j.post( ajaxurl, {
                    data: { template : str },
                    action: 'ecbs_populate_admin_template'
                }, function ( response ) {
                    //alert(response);
                    $j("#ecbs-edit-area").html( response );
                }
                        );
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    })
            .change();
});
```

Everything else works. It's just this annoying issue with the background. I have been searching for things like "ajax update backround" and "ajax redraw background," but keep coming up with nothing.

So far, I have tried this:

```
$j('body').css('background-color', rgb(248, 248, 255));
```

and this:

```
document.bgColor='#FFFFFF';
```

In the response function. No luck.

I've been able to sort of fix it by setting the height of the page so that it is taller than the edit box before anything is selected. It's an okay fix, but I'd still like to know if I can dynamically update the page background without refreshing the page.

---

Okay, here is the php. The functions just return some formatted html:

```
function ecbs_populate_admin_template() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['data'] ) && $_POST['data']['template'] != '' ) {

        $ecbs_template_id = $_POST['data']['template'];

        $ecbs_templates = get_option( ECBS_TEMPLATES );
        $ecbs_template = $ecbs_templates[$ecbs_template_id];


        die( ecbs_format_template_edit_pane( $ecbs_template_id, $ecbs_template ) );
    } else {
        die( 'No data to display' );
    }
}
```

The form updates and displays properly and when I submitted the POST data is correct.

Comment: Did you `echo json_encode($dataAssocArray);` on your PHP page? Also, your response would have to be a string to go into HTML like that. You want the last argument of `$j.post()` to set the `dataType`.

Comment: No.. I formatted the html and then did `die( $html );`. I tried changing it to the `echo jason_encode( $html )`, but it is still not updating the background properly.

Comment: What is `ajaxurl`? It needs to be valid to get a response. Also, `'rgb(248,248,255)'` should be a String, and it's `document.body.bgColor = '#fff';`.

Comment: `ajaxurl` is defined by wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Changing `'rgb(248,248,255)'` to a string causes the background area to update everywhere except the area where it was forced to scroll, which remains flat grey. Figures. I'll probably stick with setting the page height, since it is giving me a workable solution for now.

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue.  Does the body have a fixed height set or can it expand? Sounds like the new content is overflowing the body.

Comment: The body didn't have a fixed height. I did change it to one so that the page is always taller than the edit area now. They prevents the issue with part of the background being the wrong color. It just looks wonky to have a page scrolling without content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `bgColor` is a property of `body` like: `document.body.bgColor = '#fff';`. Additionally, you forgot quotes around `rgb(248, 248, 255)`. It's:
`$j('body').css('background-color', 'rgb(248, 248, 255)');`

Comment: Those things are true, but unfortunately it still doesn't update the area that was forced to scroll.